# find files in a directory but do not search in sub directroies

Tags: linux, find

i have some issue
having a directory LOG. in that so many files and directories are there. i want to find and delete the file which starts with PS. but it should not check sub directories.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` tool with  `maxdepth` option:

```
find LOG-PATH -maxdepth 1 -regextype "posix-egrep" -regex '.*/PS.*' -type f -exec rm {} \;
```